# javascript confirm() terminate my script when dialog opened

Tags: javascript

i have script for showing seconds of the hour, demo jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ahasbiyatmoko/gppwwq2o/)

following my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateClock() {
    var now = new Date();
    var seconds = now.getSeconds();

    var elem = document.getElementById('clock');
    elem.innerHTML =  seconds;
}

function confirma(){
    confirm('confirmation?');
}
</script>

<body onload="setInterval('updateClock()', 200);">
<h1 id="clock"></h1>
    <button onclick="confirma()">confirm!</button>
 </body>
```

my script works well, but when i click button "confirm!", the seconds not increase (freeze), 
why?

Comment: I think because JavaScript is single threaded, so setInterval function does not run in the "background" in the sense you've expected. In short it just schedules an automatic call. The confirm (or alert or prompt) function blocks the JavaScript execution while the message is shown.

Comment: @Zoltan how to keep the second run when dialog opened?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pyRz9/24/ ?

Comment: @RahulTripathi, not like that..
my problem is the seconds not increase (stopped) when dialog 'confirm' opened..

Comment: @ahm As far as I know, there is no way with built-in confirm dialog, because this is the standard browser behaviour. You have to use some third-party dialog iimplementation like jQuery UI or Bootstrap.

Comment: @Zoltan yes, i think so.. i only curious with 'confirm()' .. hhe
thanks for your answer before..

Comment: Don't use `setTimeout` nor `setInterval` with strings, because it's like evil `eval`! Use functions instead: `setInterval(updateClock, 200)`.

Comment: the answer from confirm('confirmation') has to be stored somewhere because it will return a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

You can pure Html instead of pop-up, becouse pop-ups will stop javascript until you click yes or no.

My suggestion is to you this put this html after your confirm button

```
<div id="test" class="testOld">
        Do you want to confirm
        <button onclick="test()">Yes</button>
        <button onclick="test2()">No</button>
    </div>
```

Add this css

```
 .testOld{
        display:none;
    }
    .testNew{
        display:block;
    }
```

And modify your javacript like this :

```
function confirma(){
    $("#test").removeClass("testOld");
     $("#test").addClass("testNew");
}
function test(){
// code after yes
}
function test2(){
//code after no
}
```